# How to divide Crystal report Page into to Section and have same Subreport?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've report my application Desktop (invoice half for company  and half for Employee) that contain of overall salary of employee and the second section contain Basic salary of the same employee 
I already have the over all data I neeed in Overall Section but

1- How to make the report page Splited into 2 sections 
2- How to join another subreport Contain basic salary only in section of Employee in report

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 sub reports one for OVerall salary and one for basic salary. and display both in detail section.

Comment: But Can I Copy The exist Subreport to the second half of report because i can't find the report which linked to and this project is existed before i join into

The Copy Subreport is All I need can I copy it ?

Comment: yes using the option `Use Existing Report` you can use the existing report as sub report.